# StackEgg voting bars are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackegg

[image: 100% bar screenshot]

[image: 50% bar screenshot]

If 100% is fill up the whole bar, shouldn't 50% be half the bar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A certain [coworker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) of mine made the same comment during development, and I see the point, but I decided to keep it the way it currently is: A full bar represents the *highest current* percentage, not 100%. So (at least) one bar is always completely filled.

This makes it harder to see what percentage of people voted for an action (though you still have the number for that), but much easier to see which action(s) is/are in the lead in the current vote, and that's the more important information here.